# Date selection in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell that has a date for my business "week ending". I would like to program three other cells to change when I change the data in cell 1.

Example:
Week Ending.   08/21/15
Wk 2.          08/27/15
Wk.3.          09/3/15
Wk 4.          09/10/15

When the week ending date is changed, the other three weeks automatically change in increments of 7 days.

Anyone know of this is possible? A million thank yous in advance!

Comment: It's possible - what have you tried so far? Do you want the dates to add 7 days *if* the cell is changed? Or do you want the dates to add 7 days *to* the new date in cell1?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the '**Add**' formula in rest of the 3 cells e.g. use the following configuration in your cells.

- Cell C1 = 08/21/15
- Cell C2 = C1 + 6
- Cell C3 = C2 + 6
- Cell C4 = C3 + 6

in this way, when you change value in C1, value of other 3 cells C2, C3 and C4 will change accordingly.